# Rule for when content is published?

Tags: 7, rules

I have the scheduler module installed, and i am using rules to notify users when new content is published.

The scheduler module is working perfect, i enter a future date and time for the content to be published. The content is published on the exact date and time.

Rules cannot action on this because there is no event coming with rules that allows me to perform some action when content is published, only when content is saved.

So my question is, how can i rules perform an action when content is published in a future date?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for something like this [module](http://drupal.org/project/revisioning)

> Rules: when Triggers won't do, use the event-condition-action paradigm of Rules. More complicated to set up than Trigger, but very powerful. Revisioning adds its own events and conditions to Rules, for example "content is about to be published" and "content has pending revisions".

and

> Revisioning is integrated with Rules, adding a number of revision-specific conditions and events.